# OpenGl surface&texture

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

I have:

- 3d pointset, which is calculated from 3d
  reconstruction process from N frame.
- sample frame snapshot (for example
  first frame when camera in (0,0,0))
- 3d to 2d corresponds

I want:

- create triangulation of point set and
  put texture (frame snapshot) on it.

How can I create this triangulation + texture via OpenGL?

Comment: Thanks=) I don't know what i must do it. I didn't notice and didn't know that I can click on this tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangulation must be part of the reconstruction process. OpenGL has nothing to do with it.

When you done the triangulation you project the texture by specifying 2d screen coordinates of the vertices in the original frame as texture UV coordinates.

Comment: I understand, that triangulation is a part of recontsrutaion. If I have a triangulation, should I add each triangle as a separate triangle ...? I think that it will not be effective ... I suggest that OpenGL must have some api like drawSurfase(pointset, triangles declaration based on pointset, (u,v) texture coordinates for each point in pointset)... does it exist?

Comment: I can't teach you OpenGl here. Find a good book or tutorial. You can use glVertexPointer family functions to directly send all your data efficiently to OpenGL.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find good examples =(
Thank you for your help! glVertexPointer will be my start point =)